# How to run express web handler after horseman in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, express, phantomjs

I was trying to scrape a website and then use it on my website. 
However, my own res.send and console.log always triggers before horseman has collected data. 
I used callback but it doesn't seem to work

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

var URL = "SomeURL";

function getProf(callback){
    var result = {com:"default", rat:"default"};
    var horseman = new Horseman();
    horseman.open(URL)
        .evaluate(function(selector){
            var els = $(selector);
            $.each(els, function(i, el) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
                event.initEvent('click', true, true);
                el.dispatchEvent(event);
            });
        }, 'h1:eq(3)')
        .delay(1000)
        .text('.metric')
        .then(function(text){
            result.com = text;   
        })
        .text('.expand-area>p')
        .then(function(text){
            result.rat = text;   
        })
        .close();
    callback(result.rat,result.com);
}

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    getProf(function(comments, rating){
        console.log(comments);
        console.log(rating);
        res.send('success');
    });
});
```

this gives me

```
default
default
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since `horseman` things are asynchronous, you need to move your `callback` to the last `.then` of `getProf` method:

```
function getProf(callback){
    var result = {com:"default", rat:"default"};
    var horseman = new Horseman();
    horseman.open(URL)
        .evaluate(function(selector){
            var els = $(selector);
            $.each(els, function(i, el) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
                event.initEvent('click', true, true);
                el.dispatchEvent(event);
            });
        }, 'h1:eq(3)')
        .delay(1000)
        .text('.metric')
        .then(function(text){
            result.com = text;   
        })
        .text('.expand-area>p')
        .then(function(text){
            result.rat = text;  
            callback(result.rat,result.com); 
        })
        .close();
}
```